# Counter variable is not changing after going through for loop

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I was working on a problem where I wanted my counter variable to decrease by one each time it goes through the for loop. It is shown here.

```
overall_triangle = """75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"""

overall_triangle_2d = [i.split() for i in overall_triangle.split('\n')]

for i in range(0, len(overall_triangle_2d)):
    for j in range(0, len(overall_triangle_2d[i])):
        overall_triangle_2d[i][j] = int(overall_triangle_2d[i][j])

counter = 13
greatest_sum = []

for i in range(0, len(overall_triangle_2d[counter])):
    print(counter)
    num_1 = int(overall_triangle_2d[counter][i]) + int(overall_triangle_2d[counter + 1][i])
    # print(num_1)
    num_2 = int(overall_triangle_2d[counter][i]) + int(overall_triangle_2d[counter + 1][i + 1])
    # print(num_2)
    empty = []
    if num_1 > num_2:
        greatest_sum.append(num_1)
    elif num_1 == num_2:
        greatest_sum.append(num_1)
    else:
        greatest_sum.append(num_2)
    # print(greatest_sum)
    if len(greatest_sum) == counter + 1:
        # print(overall_triangle_2d[counter + 1])
        overall_triangle_2d[counter + 1] = empty
        # print(overall_triangle_2d[counter + 1])
        # print(overall_triangle_2d[counter])
        overall_triangle_2d[counter] = greatest_sum
        # print(overall_triangle_2d[counter])
        # print(counter)
        if counter == 0:
            print(greatest_sum)
            break
        else:
            greatest_sum = []
            counter = counter - 1
            # print(counter)
    else:
        continue
```

Each time I run it through the counter variable does not change. Please let me know what I can do to make this work.

Comment: what is overall_triangle_2d?

Comment: I edited the problem so now you can see it

Comment: The first loop converted everything to integers, why do you use `int()` when setting `num_1` and `num_2`?

Comment: You only change `counter` when `len(greates_sum) == counter + 1`. Are you sure that condition becomes true?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `range(len(somelist))`. Use `for element in somelist:`. If you need the indexes as well, use `for i, element in enumerate(somelist):`

Comment: You can combine the first `if` and `elif` by using `>=`.

Comment: You can also just write `greatest_sum.append(max(num1, num2))`

Comment: Ok
1. I changed the int() when setting num_1 and num_2
2. Yes I am sure it is true because you can take a smaller and simpler version and look at it and it is true
3. I have never learned this type of writing it. Could you elaborate a little bit more on that?
4. Oh yes thank you I will do that
5. How would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration you add a value (num_1 or num_2) to list greatest_sum, then you have the condition `if len(greatest_sum) == counter + 1:` before decrementing the counter, so you have to wait counter+1 iterationa before having len(greatest_sum) == counter + 1, and the range of your iteration is len(overall_triangle_2d[counter]) which is counter+1, so this if statement return true in the last iteration and it decrements the counter value to 12, can you explain what is the goal of your code?

Comment: The goal of the code is to find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle

Comment: the maximum between the sum of each columns?

Comment: I am doing problem 18 on Project Euler. Here is the link. https://projecteuler.net/problem=18

I do not want the answer just why the counter is not working and anything else you may find.